# Обработчик события 'click' в Сафари

Tags: javascript, safari

Сделал подобную конструкцию в js:

```
let safariEl = document.querySelector('.header__logo')
```

```
safariEl.addEventListener('click', () => {alert('yo')})
```

все прекрасно отрабатывает в **Chrome** и **Firefox**, но на **Safari** ни в какую.

Частично решил проблему - вешаю в html атрибут `onclick`.
Но не знаю как передать через этот атрибут в функцию событие.

**Два вопроса:**

- Почему `addEventListener` не работает в Safari?
- Как поймать событие в функции вызванной из атрибута `onclick`?

Comment: Ошибки - в консоли браузера.

Comment: естественно я туда смотрел. там их нет

Comment: вопрос можно закрывать, мой косяк. все работает